# Eyeshot Sketcher Demo 2022.2 - how to change the position of a dimension constraint?

Tags: eyeshot

This is a current look of a dimension where the text is placed completely **above** the dimension line. How do I change the text position so it is placed at the **middle** of the dimension line? This may require some opacity setting so the the dimension line does not strike the text.

[image]

To

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dimension style is, in general, not supported in Eyeshot yet.